# Autoincrease SQL Azure quota

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Is there a best practice on how to handle quota limits on sql azure? maybe some sort of autoincrease?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "quota limits" - are you talking about the limits within your subscription? Or something else? Note: the notion of *quotas* is very specific to subscription limits.

Comment: Storage... how to handle when it reached my 1gb quota

Answer (score 2):

You can identify the size limit for the tier using below query:

```
SELECT Edition = DATABASEPROPERTYEX('db1', 'EDITION'),
        ServiceObjective = DATABASEPROPERTYEX('db1', 'ServiceObjective'),
        MaxSizeInBytes =  DATABASEPROPERTYEX('db1', 'MaxSizeInBytes');
```

You can then monitor current database size of the database running the following query

```
select sum(reserved_page_count) * 8.0 / 1024 as "size in MB" from sys.dm_db_partition_stats
```

And you can issue an ALTER DATABASE statement scaling up the tier as shown below:

```
ALTER DATABASE [db1] MODIFY (EDITION = 'Premium', MAXSIZE = 1024 GB, SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'P15');
```